# Debian bootdisk USB partitioned, lost access to most of space

Tags: usb, partitioning

I own a gold Kingston DataTraveler USB drive, and I recently used it as a bootdisk for a new computer.
I haven't touched it since then, but today I plugged it in and found that most of the space had become unreadable. It was originally 14.6 GB but I lost access to most of it. I can only access 396KB of it and using Windows to format it does nothing. Four kilobytes are used up for some reason.

I need to know how to get my space back. (Yes, I backed up the drive before using as a bootdisk.) (made a bootdisk with win32 diskimager, and a debian 8.0.0 install iso (not netinstall))

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution myself.
Write another image to the disk, then use Windows to format it.